# Attach to process on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I trying to do something very simple here. 
I use Visual Studio 2012. I created simple visual Studio class called BLA. The whole code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BLA
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void hit() {
            Console.Write("sdf");
        }
    }
}
```

I build it without errors. I put a breakpoint in "Console.Write("sdf")" and then try attach to process to iexplore.exe. 
The process it attached but I get an error 
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for the document.

I tried searching in google and stackoverflow I got many answers but none of them solved my problem.

Any idea how?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do you expect a class you created to be loaded by Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of application are you building, you mention that you attach to iexplore.exe is it a webapplication?

You could allways try `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` to give you a debugging option.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the object of class `Class1` and call the method `hit()` from that object.